# Flume hdfs sink

Tags: flume

I am trying to use Flume with hdfs as sink. File is getting exported. But I want to customize the name of the output file. I am using hdfs.filePrefix property for it. It is always creating a file with FlumeData.timestamp.

Comment: Could you post your entire configuration file please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please paste your configuration.

I tried it and it did work.

**My setting:**

```
agent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.filePrefix = stackoverflow
```

and I get the expected result.